# AWS CDK Avoid cloudfront cache for specific files in s3

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm creating a cloudfront distribution stack as follows:

```
const cf = new cloudfront.Distribution(this, `${appName}-${stageName}-cf-distribution`, {
      
      defaultBehavior: {
        viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
        origin: new origins.HttpOrigin(`s3-${appName}-${stageName}-${region}.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com`),
      },
      
      errorResponses: [
        {
          httpStatus: 403,
          responseHttpStatus: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/index.html'
        },
        {
          httpStatus: 404,
          responseHttpStatus: 200,
          responsePagePath: '/index.html'
        }
      ],
      domainNames: domainNames,
      defaultRootObject: 'index.html',
      certificate: cert,
    });

}
```

I want to avoid the cloudfront distribution caching for specific files (like index.html). How can I achieve it?

Comment: You do this by setting Cache-control metadata on the index.html object when you upload it to s3. Many s3 deployments systems for SPAs do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the answer as it may help someone else.
We can achieve this by defining a cache policy and attaching it to the cloudfront distribution using `addBehaviour` method as follows:

```
const noCachePolicy = new cloudfront.CachePolicy(this, `noCachePolicy-${appName}-${stageName}-cac1-01`, {
      cachePolicyName: `NoCachePolicy-${appName}-${stageName}-cac1-01`,
      defaultTtl: Duration.minutes(0),
      minTtl: Duration.minutes(0),
      maxTtl: Duration.minutes(0),

    });
    cf.addBehavior('index.html', new origins.HttpOrigin(`s3-${appName}-${stageName}-cac1-01.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com`), {
      viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      cachePolicy:noCachePolicy,
    });
```